# Binary Tree level order Traversal debug

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

I have this binary tree

```
    3
   / \
  9  20
    /  \
   15   7
```

i want to print its level order traversal in this format

```
[
  [3],
  [9,20],
  [15,7]
]
```

so i wrote this code using a queue and two lists

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> levelOrder(TreeNode root) {
        Queue<TreeNode> queue=new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
        List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<Integer>> res=new LinkedList<>();
        if(root!=null)
        {
            queue.add(root);
        }

        while(!queue.isEmpty())
        {
            int size=queue.size();
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            {

            TreeNode tempNode=queue.poll();
            list.add(tempNode.val);
            if(tempNode.left!=null)
                queue.add(tempNode.left);
            if(tempNode.right!=null)
                queue.add(tempNode.right);
            }
            res.add(list);
            list.clear();

        }

        return res;

    }
}
```

but when i check the output it returns

```
[[],[],[]]
```

i have spent more than 1 hour to debug the problem and i am convinced that my code is correct (which is not!)
i dont know what is clearing the res list after i am adding the data to it.
please help me to fix the error.

i believe list.clear() also clears the added list item in res.

of this is so then suppose

```
x=34;
list.add(x);
x=45;
System.out.println(list); // it will still print [34]
```

but using list of list and after adding item to it and if you modify inner list.. it also modifies your list of list .
why ?

```
int x=3;
li.add(x);
x=45;
res.add(li);
System.out.println(li);
li.remove(0);
li.add(23);
System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: Start by replacing  `list.clear();` with `list=new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Relevant: [Add an object to an ArrayList and modify it later](//stackoverflow.com/q/7080546)

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 1):

*This happens because you're manipulating an Object, it does not happen on primitive types*

---

You're using a single `list` instance, after you add the list in the outer list, you're still manipulating the same one, you're alwys referencing the **same** `List` instance

You're adding it multiple times in the outer list and clear it, you need to create new instance at each iteration :

```
while(!queue.isEmpty()){
    int size = queue.size();
    for(int i=0 ; i<size;i++){
        TreeNode tempNode = queue.poll();
        list.add(tempNode.val);
        if(tempNode.left!=null)
            queue.add(tempNode.left);
        if(tempNode.right!=null)
            queue.add(tempNode.right);
    }
    res.add(list);
    list = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: @MridulMittal it happens on Object, not on primitive types

Comment: @MridulMittal primitive types don't have methods like clear() that you could call on them. So it really isn't comparable.

Answer (score 0):

my working code in c++ using level order traversal

**output:**

```
[
  [ 10 ],
  [ 11  9 ],
  [ 7  12  15  8 ],
  [ 13  14  16  18 ],
]
```

**code:**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 


struct node{
    int key;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};


struct node *newnode(int key){
    struct node *Node= new node;
    Node->key=key;
    Node->left=NULL;
    Node->right=NULL;
    return Node;
}

void printNestedList(list<list<int> > nested_list) 
{ 
    cout << "[\n"; 

    list<list<int> >::iterator nested_list_itr; 

    for (nested_list_itr = nested_list.begin(); 
         nested_list_itr != nested_list.end(); 
         ++nested_list_itr) { 

        cout << "  ["; 

        list<int>::iterator single_list_itr; 

        list<int>& single_list_pointer = *nested_list_itr; 

        for (single_list_itr = single_list_pointer.begin(); 
             single_list_itr != single_list_pointer.end(); 
             single_list_itr++) { 
            cout << " " << *single_list_itr << " "; 
        } 
        cout << "],\n"; 
    } 
    cout << "]"; 
} 



void levelorder_traversal(struct node *temp){

    int l=1,level=1; 
    pair <struct node *, int> p;
    queue<pair <struct node *, int> > q;
    q.push(make_pair(temp, l));


    list<list<int> > nested_list; 
    list<int> single_list; 

    single_list.push_back(temp->key); 

    while(!q.empty()){

        struct node *temp= q.front().first;
        l= q.front().second;
        q.pop();

        if(temp->left){
            p = make_pair(temp->left, (l+1));
            q.push(p);

            if(l+1>level){
                nested_list.push_back(single_list);
                single_list.erase(single_list.begin(),single_list.end());
                level++;
            }
            single_list.push_back(temp->left->key);     
        }

        if(temp->right){
            p = make_pair(temp->right, (l+1));
            q.push(p);

            if(l+1>level){
                nested_list.push_back(single_list);
                single_list.erase(single_list.begin(),single_list.end());
                level++;
            }
            single_list.push_back(temp->right->key);            
        }

        if(q.empty()){
            nested_list.push_back(single_list);
        }   
    }
    cout<<endl;

    printNestedList(nested_list);     
}


int main(){

    struct node* root = newnode(10); 
    root->left = newnode(11); 
    root->left->left = newnode(7); 
    root->left->right = newnode(12); 
    root->right = newnode(9); 
    root->right->left = newnode(15); 
    root->right->right = newnode(8); 
    root->left->left->left = newnode(13); 
    root->left->left->right = newnode(14); 
    root->left->right->left = newnode(16); 
    root->left->right->right = newnode(18); 

    levelorder_traversal(root);
}
```